# Datatable:xml query for xml column

Tags: sql, vb.net, datatable, xquery

If i load xml datatype column to a datatable then can i perform xml query on it? SQL server supports queries like .exist, .value on xml columns. I am trying those kind of queries on datatable.

Below is a part of code which shows where i am getting error.

```
Private Sub Button15_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button15.Click
        Dim timDiff As Double
        Dim iter1 As Integer

        TextBox1.Text &= Button15.Text & vbNewLine & "      Iterations: " & TextBox2.Text & vbNewLine
        timDiff = DateAndTime.Timer
        Dim SqlAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter

        Dim strTemp As String
        Dim iRow As Integer

        Dim rConn As New SqlConnection("data source=pc91\sqlexpress;user id=admin;password=abc;initial catalog=Checklists;connect timeout=2000;")
        rConn.Open()

        SqlAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter
        sDataSet = New DataSet
        sqldatatable = Nothing


        SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = New SqlCommand("select * from DesignChanges", rConn)
        SqlAdapter.Fill(sDataSet, "tmpTable")
        sqldatatable = sDataSet.Tables("tmpTable")

        For iter1 = 1 To Val(TextBox2.Text)
            Try
                For iRow = 0 To sqldatatable.Rows.Count - 1
                    strTemp = sqldatatable.Rows(iRow).Item("AllotedTo").ToString
                Next iRow
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.ToString & Space(10) & Err.Description)
            End Try
        Next
        rConn.Close()


        SqlAdapter.Dispose()
        rConn.Dispose()

        sDataSet = Nothing
        SqlAdapter = Nothing
        rConn = Nothing
        timDiff = DateAndTime.Timer - timDiff
        TextBox1.Text &= "      Total Time Taken: " & timDiff & vbNewLine
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button17_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button17.Click
        bs.DataSource = sqldatatable
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bs

    End Sub

    Private Sub Button18_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button18.Click

       bs.Filter = "[UserApproval].exist ('/Root/Row[User=''xyz'']') =1"

    End Sub
End Class
```

In the above code error comes like "The expression contains undefined function call UserApproval.exist()." for the line bs.Filter = "[UserApproval].exist ('/Root/Row[User=''xyz'']') =1" .

If i use .value function then error will come as "The expression contains undefined function call UserApproval.value()."

But the same functions works in SQL query for sql server.

Comment: What does `.Value` expose?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can. Did you read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189075.aspx)? What kind of queries do not work well?

Comment: The link you mentioned is for sql server.But i want xml queries to be performed on datatable.